# GPS coordinates

Tags: arduino-uno, tinygps

how do I compare coordinates I receive from the GPS module with the coordinates that I had hardcoded into the arduino, for example:

if (GPS reading <= hardcoded)
   movecarforward();
else
   movecarback();

the coordinates I get keep going up and down which makes it difficult for me to compare and excute the function below.Please help.....

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the codes for this reverse geocaching project at https://learn.adafruit.com/reverse-geocache-engagement-box/software or the dog collar project at https://learn.adafruit.com/gps-dog-collar to get some help. For my GPS project I just wanted to display the distance and speed, so all I had to do was save the current location, subtract it from the previous location and add it to distanceTraveled. It'd be helpful if you could share your code here.